# angular-in-memory-web-api module not fount after import

Tags: angular

I was just trying to learn from the documentation and they have on step 6 where they talk about HTTP stuff the step where I have to install angular-in-memory-web-api using the following command :

npm install angular-in-memory-web-api --save

I did it and everything went good but when I import the package then it does not find the path and I don't know why. I tried to search on the internet but I did not find a fix.

Below you can find the error that I get.

Kind regards and kudos to anyone that can help me with the problem.

[image]

This is the log of what I get after I run the line of code above :
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you were in the "app" directory when you installed your package ? And not in a parent or sub directory...

Comment: I did it now also in the app directory and still nothing, I have the same problem

Comment: And check in your package.json to see if your dependency has been added

Comment: If it has, then try to run `npm install -i`

Comment: https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api Just follow the documentation.

Comment: `npm install angular-in-memory-web-api --save` will not add a file `in-memory-data.service` into your project. No wonder, your `import ...` is not working, how can you import something what is not there

Comment: How can I add it to my project if I may ask? I am new so everything is 100% new and I don't know who to do it. Kind regards